# How can I write a function for $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For $a,b\neq 0$, let $c$ be

- $1$ if $a$ and $b$ both are positive.
- $-1$ if any one of $a$ or $b$ is negative or  both are negative.

How can I write a function for $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You should add some more context and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: What about if a and b are both negative? The "or" is exclusive?

Comment: How about $$c(a,b) = \begin{cases} 1 & a \text{ and } b \text{ both are positive}\\ -1 & \text{any one out of } a \text{ or } b \text{ is negative} \end{cases}$$ since it is rather unclear what you are trying to ask

Comment: @glowstonetrees i want something sort of including |.|, like if we had c=1 for positive a , and -1 for negative a, then c=|a|/a

Comment: You have already described it. What do you mean by "finding out what $c$ is"?

Comment: @dbx c in terms of a and b

Comment: You might try $c = \min(\text{sign}(a),\text{sign}(b))$.  You didn't say what $c$ is if $a$ or $b$ is $0$ and neither is negative, though.

Comment: As @dbx said, you've already defined $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. What more do you mean by "finding out what $c$ is"?

Comment: What if one or both of $a$ or $b$ are zero?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the problem with $0$ you can write $$c=\min\left(\frac a{|a|},\frac b{|b|}\right)$$ but that is really no different from the case statement you rejected in the comments.  What is wrong with definition by cases?

Answer (score 1):

We can consider for $ab\neq 0$ and assuming $(-1)^{-1}=-1$ and $0^0=1$

$$c=-\left(\frac{-a|b|-|a|b}{2|ab|}\right)^{\left(\frac{-a|b|-|a|b}{2|ab|}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use $f(x) = \frac{|x|}{x}$ to map positive, non-zero numbers to 1 and negative numbers to -1. From here, $c = f(a)\cdot f(b)$ works for three of the four cases. To make it work for the last case, we hope to change 1 to negative 1 if a and b both negative and no change otherwise. Just multiply by $(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2})^{\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}}$.

$$c = \frac{|a|}{a}\cdot \frac{|b|}{b} \cdot \bigg(\frac{ \frac{|a|}{a}+ \frac{|b|}{b} }{2}\bigg)^{ \big(\frac{\frac{|a|}{a}+\frac{|b|}{b}}{2}\big)}$$

Comment: You gave me an idea to deal with the case a and b with different sign!